# Debugging application.match

Tags: excel, vba

I am reviewing code that worked for long time.

The following line of code, inside a loop, gives me an error. (i.e. Match does not find any hit in the range):

```
Application.Match(.Cells(lngRowCnt, 1).Value, wkbExternalExcel2.Worksheets(strSQOrderProcCurrentWks).columns("H"), 0)
```

but the value I am looking for exists.

To troubleshoot I run the following in the immediate window:

```
print Application.CountIf(wkbExternalExcel2.Worksheets(strSQOrderProcCurrentWks).columns("H"), .Cells(lngRowCnt, 1).Value)
 1
print application.Match(.Cells(lngRowCnt, 1).Value, wkbExternalExcel2.Worksheets(strSQOrderProcCurrentWks).columns("H"), 0)
Error 2042
```

This proves that the data is there and Match should return a row number. How can I troubleshoot this further to figure out why Match is failing?

**Edit**
The issue does not come from one specific value in the loop because it fails for each iteration (before my review it worked as expected and the review did not affect the source data where looking for a match.

I implemented the following workaround but it is ugly and inefficient so I would really like to figure out why `Match` stopped working.

```
vntVLookUpResult1 = CVErr(xlErrNA)
If Not wkbExternalExcel2.Worksheets(strSQOrderProcCurrentWks).Columns("H").Find(.Cells(lngRowCnt, 1).Value, , xlValues, xlWhole) Is Nothing Then vntVLookUpResult1 = wkbExternalExcel2.Worksheets(strSQOrderProcCurrentWks).Columns("H").Find(.Cells(lngRowCnt, 1).Value, , xlValues, xlWhole).Row
```

Comment: Check if the value in `.Cells(lngRowCnt, 1).Value` is an error variant, i.e. `#NA`. Such case will be counted in `CountIf` but not matched with `Match`.

Comment: The value exist, I can find it by manually looking in the data and also the find function finds and returns it: `wkbExternalExcel2.Worksheets(strSQOrderProcCurrentWks).Columns("H").Find(.Cells(lngRowCnt, 1).Value, , xlValues, xlWhole)` gives the expected value; the source contains just text and no #NA "strings"

Comment: Another possibility is that one of the cells is a number while the other is formatted as string. For example, `.Cells(lngRowCnt, 1).Value` = `123` and the found cell is something like `'123` or `=123 & ""`.

Comment: Assuming this is true, how would I overcome this? and why would `CountIf` and even `Find` work? Anyway, this cannot be the case because the Match line was working perfectly before my review and the source data did not change. In addition, the Match fails for each single value in the column, so it is not dependent on the single loop iteration. I will add the latter info in the main question text.